# Enabling Double Length Pseudolanguage doesn't work in Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, nslocalizedstring

I'm trying to use the Double Length Pseudolanguage to test potential layout problems with other languages. I've enabled **Application Language -> Double Length PseudoLanguage** in scheme editor but when I run the app in the simulator, none of the strings were doubled. I've tried preview editor in Storyboards and the strings stayed the same.

FYI: I have localized my app to two languages already, I have a Base language (English) and pt-br (Portuguese). All of my hardcoded strings were changed in code to use NSLocalizedString.

Comment: I am having the same problem.  Sometimes it works sometimes it doesn.t

Answer (score 4):

This might sound completely unrelated to the topic, but believe me, I read the question correctly.

If you use AFNetworking pod, go to AFURLSessionManager.m -> _AFURLSessionTaskSwizzling implementation and comment out the line `[localDataTask cancel]`. If you use CocoaPods you might get a warning that you have to unlock editing of the file. That fixes it for me.

Comment: This fixed it for me too. Thank you!

Comment: How does commenting this out effect the app? Does it mean, that we cannot have "Show non-localized strings" always turned on?

Comment: Ran into this issue as well. Found a thread on the issue. No fix has been found yet. https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/3303

Answer (score 3):

Try testing it on a real device.

Looks like this is a bug of the simulator on newer versions of Xcode.

Comment: Faced same issue with xcode 9, Its not loading double length pseudo language on simulator but on device it loads.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue both with Xcode 7.3 and 8 Beta. If you run on iOS 8 simulator this seem to work. Not ideal, but better than nothing.